# Config test failed when restarting Apache

Tags: apache2, php

When I tried to restart apache2 i got the following error.

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 14 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/httpd.conf:
Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The contents of `httpd.conf` is as follows.

```
<Directory "/var/www">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that syntax in the config file at line `14`:

```
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
```